# Assembling block matrix with Numba support

Tags: python, numpy, numba

In my code (written in Python 2.7), I create two numpy arrays, `A` and `B`. I then use them to assemble a larger matrix, `H`, with the following code

`H = np.block([A, B], [-B, -A])`

Various computations follow, involving substantial amounts of numpy manipulations and for loops. As a result, I would like to use Numba to optimize the code. However, it appears that the numpy block function is unsupported in Numba. The matrices `A` and `B` are not terribly large, so I'm fine using a function that may not be as optimized as `np.block`, but I would still like to assemble `H` in a block matrix fashion for the purpose of readability. Are there any functions that would accomplish this?

Comment: The working core of `block` is in `np.core.shape_base._block`.  It does a recursive `_block` and `concatenate` on each axis.  In your case that's 3 concatenates.  `concatenate` is already compiled code.

Answer (score 0):

Just to make @hpaulj's comment concrete, making some basic assumptions about your input data and not doing any sort of error checking:

```
@nb.njit
def nb_block(X):
    xtmp1 = np.concatenate(X[0], axis=1)
    xtmp2 = np.concatenate(X[1], axis=1)
    return np.concatenate((xtmp1, xtmp2), axis=0)
```

The following also works:

```
@nb.njit
def nb_block2(X):
    xtmp1 = np.hstack(X[0])
    xtmp2 = np.hstack(X[1])
    return np.vstack((xtmp1, xtmp2))
```

and the performance of the two differs with different sized arrays. You should benchmark your own application.

Then calling:

```
A = np.zeros((50,30))
B = np.ones((50,30))

X = np.block([[A, B], [-B, -A]])
Y = nb_block(((A, B), (-B, -A)))  # Note the tuple-of-tuples vs list-of-lists
np.all_close(X, Y)  # True
```